TUniQuery replacing spaces with question marks. The spaces come from calls to TimeToStr(MyTTimeVar). It only happens on 64bit Android. Why?
I have the following code:
var Date: TDate := now;
var Time: TTime := now;
...
var Text: string := trim(DateToStr(Date)) + '|' + trim(TimeToStr(Time));
UniQuery1.FieldByName('BATCH DATA').AsString := Text;

After this code, the Text variable still contains 9/6/24|8:14:15 AM as you would expect.
However, UniQuery1.FieldByName('BATCH DATA').AsString contains 9/6/24|8:14:15?AM.
In other words, assigning the value to a TUniQuery field swapped the space for a ?.
The database it is connected to is a SQLite database that is UTF-8 encoded. I'm using Delphi 11.3 Alexandria.
I'm assuming this has something to do with character encoding, but I have no idea why a space would be encoded differently or how to see or change the character encoding of the string that comes from TimeToStr().
The really odd thing is this doesn't happen on 32bit or 64bit Windows or our 32bit Samsung Tab Active 2 Android tablets. It copies the Text variable with the original spaces. However, we just upgraded to Samsung Tab Active 5 Tablets which are 64bit tablets and that's when the behavior changed.
Please help! I have been beating my head against this for days! What can I do to try to resolve this?

Do you have the same problem with FormatDateTime()? Have you tried enumerating the string logging the numeric value of its characters? Sounds like maybe the space in question is a Unicode space instead of an ASCII space

@RemyLebeau Switching to FormatDateTime resolved the issue! Thank you so much! It does seem that TimeToStr was returning a unicode string on Android 64bit only for some reason, but FormatDateTime did not have that issue. If you would like to leave it as an answer I will accept it.

It would still be nice to know exactly what whitespace character TimeToStr() is actually outputting. I suspect it is something like U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE instead of U+0020 SPACE. Why TUniQuery isn't handling this character correctly, I do not know. UTF-8 can encode the entirely of Unicode, so there has be a bug somewhere in Uni's logic.

@RemyLebeau I just checked and the space that returns from the TimeToStr function on my 64bit tablet is a 'NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+202F). I also double checked and if run the same basic code on Windows or my 32bit tablet, it is just a normal U+0020 space instead of the narrow no break space. I have no idea why TimeToStr would change what kind of space it uses just for one platform?

Double-check the global SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat variable, it likely has the U+202F character in it. If so, then it is coming from the Android OS itself. If needed, you can call TimeToStr() with a local TFormatSettings variable so that you can provide your own LongTimeFormat string. Though, since you are concatenating date and time together, FormatDateTime() just makes more sense
